# apache2 - mod_rewrite problems

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, apache2

I am trying to rewrite a URL so that it does this:

This: `domain/404?hello` to `domain/e.php?n=404&u=hello` where 404 is static, but string `u` can vary.

This is what I've tried, but it does not work.

`RewriteRule ^404?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ e.php?n=404&u=$1`

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work means does not redirect at all or does not give you the right result?

Comment: The RewriteRule is totally ignored. It is not a problem with mod_rewrite though. I'm succesfully redirecting other URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-z0-9-_]+)
RewriteRule ^404(.*) /e.php?n=404&u=%1
```